# Replace several numbers in an array every step in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, search, matrix, indexing

I am having a set of data. Let's say a grid-points nxm (n latitude, m:longitude) daily temperature for the whole world during a month. However, the temperature in my location of interest is not correct, so I need to update it. In other words, I have to change the data at some certain grid points for every time step (daily). I attach here a simple example. Let's say each matrix 1x2 on the left is the correct data, while each 6x4 matrix contains some incorrect data (6: latitude, 4: longitude). What I need is to change the correct data from the left to the right as indicated in the same color for every time step.

Could anyone help me?

Many thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For example this data:

```
A=rand(4,2)
B=rand(6,4,4)
```

You would want these values to be replaced by A:

```
B(3,2:3,:)
```

Just make sure the size is the same

```
size(B(3,2:3,:))
> 1 2 4
A=reshape(A',[1 2 4])
```

And you can put it there

```
B(3,2:3,:)=A
```

[edit] Sorry, I probably just don't see the problem.

```
T = randi(255,[1E3,1E3,31],'uint8'); %1000 longitude, 1000 latitude, 31 days
C = repmat([50,100],[31,1,1]); %correction for 31 days and two locations. must become 50 and 100. 
%location 20,10 and 20,11 must change.
T(20,10:11,:)=reshape(C',[1 2 31]);
T(20,10,3) %test for third day.
>> 50
T(20,11,10) %test for tenth day.
>> 100
```

The replacement takes 0.000365 second on my pc.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but that is an example. Actually I have long, and large matrices, so I guess I have to use a LOOP, but still don't know how.

Comment: The size should not matter, the same principle applies. If you example is bad, please update it.

Comment: @Barack You should exactly explain what you know. How do you know which elements to replace? Please update your question to include this information.

Comment: Sorry I have updated the question. Also, my apologies for bad written language.

Comment: I have updated my answer, but I don't see what you find so difficult with this simple replacement of parts of a matrix. It's what Matlab was build for to do. That's why it can do it so fast.